# Jquery - allow form submit and override preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to test and make sure at least one form field is filled out:

```
function checkFields(form) {
    var checks_radios = form.find(':checkbox, :radio'),
            inputs = form.find(':input').not(checks_radios).not('[type="submit"],[type="button"],[type="reset"]'); 

    var checked = checks_radios.filter(':checked');
    var filled = inputs.filter(function(){
            return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0;
    });

    if(checked.length + filled.length === 0) {
            return false;
    }

    return true;
```

}

And that is called when the form is submitted:

```
$(function(){
    $('.checkThisForm').on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var oneFilled = checkFields($(this));
            if (!(oneFilled)) {
                    alert('You must fill in at least one field');
            } else {
                    /* ??? */
            }
    });
```

});

What goes in my else { } to allow the form to submit if the user has supplied at least one element to search for in the form?

Comment: Try `this.submit()`.

Comment: Maybe try putting `e.preventDefault();` inside your if-statement, so you only prevent the default functionality when needed (and thus remove the else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` for form action will indicate to proceed or stop the submission

```
$('.checkThisForm').on('submit',function(e){
    var oneFilled = checkFields($(this));
    if (!(oneFilled)) {
        alert('You must fill in at least one field');
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are required to follow below info. First you need to triger click event and submit

```
$(function(){
$('.checkThisForm').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var oneFilled = checkFields($(this));
        if (!(oneFilled)) {
                alert('You must fill in at least one field');
        } else {
                this.submit();
        }
});
```

Comment: Make sure you button need to have type="button"